# How can I bypass cache when redis goes down?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using node.js, MySQL database, and redis server as a cache server. If redis is down or otherwise unavailable, then I want to get data from the MySQL server, so that the API isn't unavailable.

Comment: You forgot to show us your code :)

Comment: restructured question to be a more specific question. Please post the code you have now.